# discord quiz bot using python

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

New to making discord bots with python. The internet and youtube didn't really give me any answers. I'll get to the point, how do I make a quiz bot on python. Which asks a question, then waits for a reply from the user, then replies whether it was the correct answer or not.

Comment: You would need to use the [`Client.wait_for_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_message) coroutine

Answer (score 0):

Check some examples on [GitHub](https://github.com), like https://github.com/Habchy/BasicBot.

If you want to develop a Discord bot, you have to use a library or create your own.

Remember the we **help you**, but we **don't develop your projects.**

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple bot which calls an an api from the site opentdb. at client even then asks a question of multiple choice then waits for response with:

```
def check(m):
  return (
    m.author == message.author
    and m.channel.id == message.channel.id
  )

# player sending answer, get letter from answer
try:
  msg = await client.wait_for("message",check = check, timeout=15.0)                                                 
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
  return await message.channel.send('Timeout')



if the_answer in msg.content:
  await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}\n'
                             f'You got it right!')
else:
  await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}\n'
                             f'You got it wrong, the correct answer was, **{the_answer}**')
```